# Airflow webserver causes OS to crash

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow on an Ubuntu VM.
Here is my config file values for Airflow:

```
plugins_folder = /home/helia/airflow/utils
dags_folder = /home/helia/airflow/dags
```

Here are my environment variables set accordingly:

```
>>echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/helia/airflow:/home/helia/airflow/utils
>>>echo $AIRFLOW_HOME
/home/helia/airflow
```

If I set my plugins folder path in the cfg file to some non-existing file, the webserver successfully starts and produces the errors fast.
Howver, if I change the cfg file plugins path to the correct path, the OS crashes every time with 100% of CPU, swap space and Memory usage.
I tried to increase number of processors and memory size but nothing got better.

I am using:

Airflow 1.10.12

Python 3.8

UBUNTU 20.1

Comment: I am afraid it's your custom plugin that crash the OS. There is not much that anyone could do without knowing and having access to your plugins. You have to revert to those  who wrote those plugins to debug them.

Comment: @JarekPotiuk but thses plugins are running on the main server :| how is this possible? I cloned them via git

Comment: Plugins are loaded by webserver (one of the features of plugins is that they can extend the UI of webserver). Depending on your deployment the "plugin" folder should be shared with the webserver (usually via shared filesystem)

Comment: @JarekPotiuk I need you to post it as an answer since it solved my problem. One of the plugins was causing the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it's your custom plugin that crash the OS. There is not much that anyone could do without knowing and having access to your plugins. You have to revert to those who wrote those plugins to debug them. –

Plugins are loaded by webserver (one of the features of plugins is that they can extend the UI of webserver). Depending on your deployment the "plugin" folder should be shared with the webserver (usually via shared filesystem) –